# Messages Gradle Build Errors

Tags: java, android

I started to to android app, and first I wrote java code in NetBeans , now this code with all libaries (jar files) I applied in Android Studio and it's not showing errors  till I run it, when i run my programm I'm getting this messages

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>       File 1: C:\Users\huse\AndroidStudioProjects\BallC\poi-3.13-20150929\poi-3.13-20150929.jar
>       File 2: C:\Users\huse\AndroidStudioProjects\BallC\poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929\poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar

I know that I have similar libaries and if delete one then I will have errors in  my java code.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

add below code to build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions { 
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

adding below code to build.gradle solved my problem

```
android { 
        .....
      packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'    }

     .... }
```